# Сохранение двойного тире в slug в WordPress

Tags: wordpress, seo

Переношу сайт с одного движка на ВордПресс.

В товарах есть URL типа `site.ru/kamera-intraoralnaya-provodnaya--md910`

Но при импорте товаров двойное тире меняется на одинарное, и получается: `site.ru/kamera-intraoralnaya-provodnaya-md910`
Изменение слага вручную не помогает, двойное тире также заменяется на одинарное.

Как в WordPress убрать замену двойного тире?

Comment: Лучшим решением будет написать редирект.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

На самом деле, все делается просто.
Помог Chat GPT

`remove_filter('sanitize_title', 'sanitize_title_with_dashes');` - вставляем в functions.php

Comment: Да, но наверное это преобразование там не просто так и может повлиять на какой-то другой функционал, о котором Вы не подозреваете. Вы меняете стандартное поведение слагов, теперь туда могут попадать пробелы, например.